# Why are images flattened out during hand written script matching in pattern matching (Neural Networks)

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm new to neural networks, I picked off with this video for a general introduction to the subject from Martin Gorner (https://youtu.be/vq2nnJ4g6N0) at around 5:23 (https://youtu.be/vq2nnJ4g6N0?t=3230), he goes on to say that the image will be flattened out from 28x28 to 1x784. Why is this step necessary ? Is it because the Weights (W) with which the X will be multiplied (cross product) with will be a a single row vector of the same length ? Like for the sake of cross product or is it something else ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing like that. The aim is purely to make things easier for newbies. Fully connected neural network, which is presented to you, is the basic building block. Later you will learn more advanced patterns.

Images contain a spatial structure and as such it would be more suitable to use an architecture that is structure-aware, e.g. Convolutional Neural Network ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network), [2](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/)). In fact if you continue watching the lecture you will find exactly that.

Comment: Thanks a lot man :D ya I did follow on the lecture after some googling :)